# Understanding action reaction in an example

Tags: classical-mechanics, acceleration

When I move an object that object should move me as well. I tried standing on a skateboard to reduce friction, and holding a heavy barbell, move myself away from it (while still holding it) but I haven't noticed any movements of a skateboard. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Did you try throwing it. or just swing it from close to far?  If the barbell only wiggled back and forth, you should only expect to wiggle back and forth yourself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just didn't throw around enough weight to overcome friction.

While technically, if you were on a completely frictionless skateboard, by simply moving the barbell around you would roll a bit (the center of mass of you and the barbell would remain stationary), in the real world you have to overcome some friction to start rolling.  Friction is typically modeled as a fixed fraction of your weight:
$$ F_{\text{friction}} = \mu m g $$
where $\mu$ is the friction coefficient, and depends on the particulars of the materials or surfaces involved.

But, we can actually generate some quantitative estimates for whether you should have expected to start moving in this case.  By moving the barbell with your arms, you are causing a force to act on the barbell. By Newton's third law, this means there is an equal and opposite force acting on you.  This force, by Newton's first second law $ \vec F = m \vec a $, will be dependent on the mass of the barbell and how quickly you manage to accelerate it.

Assuming you weigh 75 kg (because its a nice number), and the barbell was 10 kg, if you threw your arms out from you, with a max speed of ~ 1 m/s at half an arm's length, you would have caused a force of magnitude:

$$ F_{\text{push}} = m_{\text{barbell}} a  = \frac{ m_{\text{barbell}} v_{\text{max}}^2 }{ 2 x_{\text{max}} }  \sim \frac{ (10 \text{ kg}) (1 \text{m/s})^2 }{ 2 (0.5 \text{ m}) } \sim 10 \text{ N} $$

Comparing this to your gravitational force:
$$ F_{\text{grav}} = m_{\text{you}} g \sim 750 \text{ N} $$

You would need the static rolling friction coefficient to be less than $10/750 \sim  0.01 $.

It is unlikely that the friction coefficient is this small.

One way to see this, is if you were to put the skateboard on an incline by itself and raise the angle until it starts to roll, we could measure the static friction coefficient for your particular surface and skateboard.  Since the ratio of the tangential force to the gravitational force is $\sin \theta \sim \theta$, even without performing the experiment we can compute the angle a friction coefficient of 0.01 would correspond to, in order to get a sense of whether we would expect you to have moved.  $\theta = 0.013 \text{ radians} \sim 1\text{ degrees}$, which looks like this:

[image: 1 degree slope]

So, assuming the parameters above are correct, the fact that you did not move is no less mysterious than if a skateboard placed on that incline were not to move, which I personally don't find too mysterious. Especially if the surface was in any way rough.

In order to make this experiment feasible you're going to have to increase something by a factor of a few (~3), either moving around a few times more weight or moving it away from you a few times faster.

Comment: So I would move opposite by throwing barbell with enough force but would I move by just strathening flexed arms holding very heavy barbell? (I feel like I miss something here)

Comment: @lijki Sorry if it was unclear.  If you were on a completely frictionless surface, just by moving your arms you would move, but in the real world you have to overcome the static friction force to start moving, in order to create a large *force* you need to move the barbell with a decent *acceleration*, especially since it is a small fraction of your mass.

Comment: So If I would be in the air with 2 weights attached to my arms(let's say 1000kg-it is just example). Now when I try to move my arms forward actually my body moves backward while my arms almost doesn't move at all. So if my arms were ultra heavy when trying to move them I would move the rest of a body instead. Is that correct? (I hope it is clear enough to know what I mean)

Comment: @lijki Yes that is correct, assuming no friction.